# How to get the current User Windows Logon Details: WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

Tags: vb.net

This code was used once to get the Current user's windows logon name.

The application was published on a webserver and this code worked to get the end user's Windows Logon Name, so how could this happen when this code is actually running in the code behind on the server itself?

Dim CurrentUser As String = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString

Please explain to me if you can.

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is; you have only said that the code worked! Does it no longer work?

Comment: No I am convinced that it worked in the past and still do so. I just don't know how to prove it and I wonder if anyone could. I am told that this would NEVER work to get the logon name of end users. It will only do so for the server where this code run. So how could it have been possible techincally to work and return the logon name of the end users of the system without any problems?!!

Answer (score 3):

IIS has a mode called Windows Authentication which (usually when combined with Internet Explorer) will authenticate the user with the server automatically and enable this functionality.

For this to work you usually have to disable anonymous access.

Comment: So this Windows Authentication will obviously occur on the IIS where this application is hosted - in other words where this code is running (On the WebServer); correct? Forgive my ignorance please I am still learning this!

Comment: Yes, the server will authenticate the user. It would also be possible to use this code in a desktop application to get the name of the currently logged on user

Comment: This may also require Impersonation turned on on the web.config I guess like this: 
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
  <authorization>

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on impersonation, but you will need the authentication tag at least